# Python Attribute Error when running script: type object 'BaseCommand' has no attribute 'option_list'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I saw this post on how to run a python script from django:  http://www.djangotutsme.com/how-to-run-python-script-from-django/
I tried the example but get the following error when running `python manage.py runscript myscript`. 
I have Python 2.7, Django 1.10 and django extensions 1.6.1 installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.dev20151201151517-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 349, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.dev20151201151517-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.dev20151201151517-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 193, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.dev20151201151517-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django_extensions.management.email_notifications import \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 10, in <module>
    class EmailNotificationCommand(BaseCommand):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 49, in EmailNotificationCommand
    **option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
AttributeError: type object 'BaseCommand' has no attribute 'option_list'**
```

Any idea what the problem is?  Is this a bug in django?

Comment: can you post the content of myscript?

Answer (score 12):

[`BaseCommand.option_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.option_list) is deprecated in Django 1.8 and removed in Django 1.10. It looks like Django-extensions [has been updated](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/commit/f3d80be6964b8498e15e40e8348c4398cf7439a5), but there hasn't been a new release since then.

You could try installing django-extensions from the master branch, but it would be a better idea to use the latest release of Django, currently 1.9.2.
Django 1.10 has not been released yet, and is still under development.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes sense! To install 1.9.2, Do I need to uninstall 1.10 or can I just remove the Django-1.10.dev20151201151517-py2.7.egg/ folder?

Comment: If you installed Django using pip, you can do `pip install django==1.9.2` and it will uninstall the old version for you. I would usually try to avoid removing egg directories.

Comment: I'm using a python install script for tarballs, written by a colleague of mine, which works brilliantly. I used it when I originally installed django, django-extensions and six. The problem is that I am using a Virtual Machine where proxy environment settings to access e.g. pypi.python.org don't work, so trying to install pip is a bit of a b---h! Anyway, after running the script and checking the path to django in python, it seems that version 1.9.2. is recognized.

Comment: >>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.pyc'>