# AttributeError: type object 'BaseCommand' has no attribute 'option_list'

Tags: python, django, solr, django-2.0

Hello i am trying to create search app in My Django project using Haystack and Solr but i receive this error "AttributeError: type object 'BaseCommand' has no attribute 'option_list'"

I am running this command : python manage.py rebuild_index

I am using :

Python 3.6.4

solr-4.10.4

haystack 2.4.0

Django 2.0

If the post isn't clear i am ready to explain it more

[See the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prq7E.png)

Comment: please post the codes that are failing, show what you have done so we understand why this is failing

Comment: There is no code just i installed django-haystack and solr-4 and trying to run this command :python manage.py rebuild_index

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate first?

Comment: no because i didn't add anything new in model.py

Comment: can you show the fullstack error you are getting?

Comment: ok done.  i just edit my post and add a picture

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, [@alasdair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181811/5259791) helped me fix it.

Basically you're using old packages with a new version of django. Downgrading your django to v1.9 or upgrading `pysolr` and `django-haystack` packages will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that updating Haystack will FORCE-UPGRADE Django to the latest version.  For production sites, that may not be advisable without testing first.